# how to insert if else in equal statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I need to set the condition as below code.

```
_orderStatus = Request.QueryString["order"] != null ? Request.QueryString["order"] : _orderStatus != "" ? _orderStatus : "pending";
```

Currently the condition only applied to show pending order. How can i change and add to get as below condtion:

```
if Request.QueryString["order"] != null then 
  _orderStatus: "pending"
else 
  _orderStatus: "confirmed"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

should be like this

```
_orderStatus = Request.QueryString["order"] != null ? "pending" : "Confirmed";
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional note to the above answer: Let me copy your requirement to the answer:

> if Request.QueryString["order"] != null then _orderStatus: "pending"
>   else _orderStatus: "confirmed"

Here you need to assign the result to the variable `_orderStatus`, The conditional operator will do that for you, you need not to do an additional assignment within the operator.

> While using conditional operator `if.. then` can be replaced with `?`
>   and else will be replaced by `:` and the result will be assigned to
>   the `_orderStatus`.

Now look into your code( which included in the answer), and apply the  replacements as i said. then you will get the answer like the following:

```
_orderStatus = Request.QueryString["order"] != null ? "pending" : "Confirmed";
```

Answer (score 0):

The bets way of checking your query string then, try this

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["order"]))
          _orderStatus = "pending";
  else
         _orderStatus = "confirmed";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do either u can simply check the for null or Empty by using if conditon like this

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["order"]))
      _orderStatus = "pending";
else
     _orderStatus = "confirmed";
```

or  you can use conditional expression [For reference u can go through this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ternary)

For your question u can use this way

```
_orderStatus = Request.QueryString["order"] != null ? "pending" : "Confirmed";
```

There's no reason to expect any difference in performance.

In my opinion, the ternary operator should only be used if all three operands are very concise and easy to read. Otherwise I think it has the potential to make code harder to read.

I think a lot of people mis-use this operator by using too much logic into one long line of code. I personally won't use it unless the whole line is less than about 80 characters.